# Click a label checkbox in Python Selenium for Accept Terms and Conditions

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

Hi I want to click this checkbox:

```
<label class="sui-AtomCheckbox sui-AtomCheckbox--medium">
    <input type="checkbox" id="isConsentApproved" name="isConsentApproved" intermediate="" value="false" tabindex="5">
</label>
```

But I can't click, as Python raises this error:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//label[@id="isConsentApproved"]"}
```

My goal is mark the [checkbox](https://www.milanuncios.com/registro) for Accept Terms And Conditions.

This my code now:

```
    driver.maximize_window()
    
    driver.get("https://www.milanuncios.com/registro")
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    button = driver.find_element_by_class_name(u"sui-AtomButton--solid")
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
    driver.find_element_by_id("name").send_keys(name)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(email)
    driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@id="isConsentApproved"]').click()
```

**---------------(EDIT)------------------**

Thanks to the collaboration of Frenchy, Python found the label, but now say this not clickable element:
**selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable**

Anyone have solution to this. The new code is this:

```
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.milanuncios.com/registro")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name(u"sui-AtomButton--solid")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
driver.find_element_by_id("name").send_keys(name)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(email)
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//input[@id="isConsentApproved"]').click()
```

**---------------(EDIT)------------------**
Now i can clcik the checkbox with JavaScript, and work! But have a problem...

After clicking it, selenium closes without showing any error

This is my new code:

```
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.milanuncios.com/registro")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name(u"sui-AtomButton--solid")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
driver.find_element_by_id("name").send_keys(name)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(email)
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="isConsentApproved"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: There's no reason to use an XPath for just an ID, e.g. `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@id="isConsentApproved"]')` should be `driver.find_element_by_id("isConsentApproved")`. If you would have done this, you would have avoided the error you got because the ID is not on the `LABEL`, it's on the `INPUT`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change HTML code with Selenium Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69667074/how-to-change-html-code-with-selenium-python)

Comment: This is a dup of the question you asked a few days ago. Don't ask the same question again... be patient and wait for an answer to your original question.

Comment: Now Python found label button, but he say not a interactable element. You can see my code now. And yes, i know it's easier with id but I want to understand the xpath since I'm just starting out and I want to know exactly how to use it :)

Comment: Sorry for that JeffC but I did not publish the other post correctly because they are my firsts posts and I did not understand well, and now i understand a little better and I decided to create another one with all the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

its not

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//label[@id="isConsentApproved"]').click()
```

its:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//input[@id="isConsentApproved"]').click()
```

[image: Site]

**EDIT**

so you cant click on input button because its not clickable, the only thing to do it is to perform a click on label:

(to be sure the element is not covered by the inital window )

```
label = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@class="ma-FormRegister-legal sui-AtomLabel sui-AtomLabel--small sui-AtomLabel--inlineLeft"]')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(label).click(label).perform()
```

Comment: Hi, he's almost there! but now with this Python say: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: the input button is not clickable, its greyed, so you have to perform a click manually on label associated with Actionchains, see my answered edited

Comment: Hi, i encountered a solution with javascript. Python check the box but when check 1 second later crash. Im going to edit the post

Comment: And the last solutions you send dont working for me, crashes when finish send password.